# How can I use Inbox for mailto: links?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I'm using Firefox 40 on Windows 10. I moved to Inbox a few days ago and I love it. My question is: how can I have Firefox use Inbox for `mailto:` links?

I know this is possible with the standard Gmail client as that's what I'm doing right now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed this is possible using the current version of Firefox, 47.0, and the [MailtoWebmails](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mailtowebmails/?src=search) addon.

1. Install the MailtoWebmails addon by going to the URL above and selecting the Add to Firefox button
2. This should open a new tab, if it doesn't then manually go to about:mailto?discover
3. Scroll down to Inbox, select Install, then make active.
4. Click on a Mailto link and an Inbox compose window will open.

Comment: Unfortunately, this extension hasn't been updated for FireFox 57 / converted to a WebExtension. Need a new solution in the modern world! `)=`

Answer (score -1):

It's available now, I just confirmed it. https://plus.google.com/+BrianCalderon/posts/4jcFyeyWt4V.

Comment: The post you're citing shows Chrome's web event handler; it's not obvious whether the same would work in Firefox.